# Why is my graphics window crashing? [Zelle Graphics]

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create the Game of Life in Python, but for some reason, my graphics window crashes during the 'run simulation' function. Why is this the case? No error on the log is given.

```
 from graphics import *  #Using zelle graphics module for Python
S=20 #Size of each cell. The bigger the number the bigger it is
class Cell: #Cell is a rectangular box. Can be alive or dead
    def __init__(self,window,x,y,alive):
        self.window=window
        self.alive=alive
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.rectangle=Rectangle(Point(x*S,(y*S)+S),Point((x*S)+S,y*S))
        self.draw(x,y,self.window) 

    def draw(self,x,y,window):
        self.rectangle.setFill("black")
        self.rectangle.draw(window)

    def getX(self):
        return self.x*S

    def getY(self):
        return self.y*S+S

    def die(self):
        self.rectangle.setFill("black")
        self.alive=False

    def becomeAlive(self,window):
        self.rectangle.setFill("white")
        self.alive=True

    def isAlive(self):
        return self.alive

    def clickedOn(self,mouseX,mouseY):
        if (mouseX>self.getX() and mouseX<self.getX()+S and mouseY<self.getY()+S and mouseY<self.getY()):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def totalNeighbours(self,cell0,cell1,cell2,cell3):
        if(cell0.isAlive() and cell0.isAlive() and cell0.isAlive() and cell0.isAlive()):
            return True


def createGraphics():    
    win=GraphWin("Game of Life!",1000,1000)
    return win

def createGrid(window):   #Creating the grid of cell objects
    cellList=[]
    for x in range(150):
        for y in range(150):
            cell=Cell(window,x,y,alive=False)
            cellList.append(cell)

    for i in range(10):
        getM=window.getMouse()
        j=0
        for cells in cellList:
            if cellList[j].clickedOn(getM.getX(),getM.getY()): #Checking whether the cell has been clicked.

                cellList[j].becomeAlive(window) 
                break
            else:
                j=j+1

    return cellList


def runSimulation(window,cellList):  #At this part my graphics window ceases functioning and the program crashes
    for i in range(10000000000):
        j=150
        for cell in cellList:
            if cell.isAlive():
                if cell.totalNeighbours(cellList[j-1],cellList[j+1],cellList[j+150],cellList[j-150])==4:
                    cellList[j].die()

            j=j+1

def main():
    window=createGraphics()
    cellList=createGrid(window)
    runSimulation(window,cellList)

main()
```

When I say 'crash' I mean the program ceases to run, and the graphics window is unresponsive. I've had these problems before and usually I just need to use the Tkinter gui in my shell configurations, but it doesn't work this time.

Comment: Your window does not crash. You run a very long loop. The window may become responsive after the loop end.

Comment: I didn't think it would make a difference how long the loop was! Just wanted to see it run for a long time! Thank you my problem's fixed